# Modifying a water irrigation timer to count in seconds instead of minutes

Tags: valve, timer

I have a washing machine that requires manual filling from the sink through an inlet hose. If you forget about filling it, the machine will overflow.

I would like to add a timer valve like the ones used in home irrigation, similar to this: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Melnor-Mechanical-Water-Timer-480-616/100659515

Unfortunately, these timers are in the order of minutes or hours rather than seconds. Is it possible to modify the timer to count down in seconds?

Comment: A float valve would cut of the water when it reaches a certain level, this may be more reliable than a timer.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you can modify that to count in seconds, but you can buy digital sprinkler timers (especially indoor propagation ones) that can be programmed down to the second.

You'd also need a valve - but the valves for sprinkler timers aren't designed for indoor use. Use at your own risk, etc.

Do you really need seconds? I'd say four or five minutes would be needed to fill a washing machine anyway, and the last bit you'd do manually, because of variance caused by the amount of clothes.

Comment: Also, daily pressure fluctuation of municipal water systems reduces precision. Minutes should be adequate.